# How can I increase the amount of array iterated during the run-time of script?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

My script cleans arrays from the unwanted string like "@#$!" and other stuff.
The script works as intended but the speed of it is extremely slow when the excel row size is big.

I tried to use numpy if it could speed it up but I'm not too familiar with is so I might be using it incorrectly.

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(path)
df = xls.parse("Sheet2")

TeleNum = np.array(df['telephone'].values)

def replace(orignstr):  # removes the unwanted string from numbers
    for elem in badstr:
        if elem in orignstr:
            orignstr = orignstr.replace(elem, '')
    return orignstr


for UncleanNum in tqdm(TeleNum):
    newnum = replace(str(UncleanNum))  # calling replace function
    df['telephone'] = df['telephone'].replace(UncleanNum, newnum)  # store string back in data frame
```

I also tried removing the method to if that would help and just place it as one block of code but the speed remained the same.

```
for UncleanNum in tqdm(TeleNum):
    orignstr = str(UncleanNum)
    for elem in badstr:
        if elem in orignstr:
            orignstr = orignstr.replace(elem, '')
            print(orignstr)
    df['telephone'] = df['telephone'].replace(UncleanNum, orignstr)
TeleNum = np.array(df['telephone'].values)
```

The current speed of the script running an excel file of 200,000 is around 70it/s and take around an hour to finish. Which is not that good since this is just one function of many.

I'm not too advanced in python. I'm just learning as I script so if you have any pointer it would be appreciated.

Edit:

Most of the array elements Im dealing with are numbers but some have string in them. I trying to remove all string in the array element.

Ex.

```
FD3459002912
*345*9002912$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to clear everything that isn't a digit from the strings you can directly use re.sub like this:

```
import re

string = "FD3459002912"
regex_result = re.sub("\D", "", string)
print(regex_result) # 3459002912
```

Comment: Thanks but its not the result im going for but ill look up on regex.

Comment: From your edit I'm getting that you just want to clear everything that is not a digit not replace anything. Is this the case ?

Comment: Yes, If char in array element is string remove char, else pass.

Comment: and just to note my script works i just want to know if the is a more efficient way of achieving the same result.

Comment: Ye I know that. The issue causing the long runtime are the 2 nested for loops which is why I'm suggesting to try something else. If you use regex sub you can both find all unwanted chars and replace them without having for loop with an if inside which should speed things up.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info about the regex sub, make my script a whole lot cleaner.
However i did find the thing that slow down the speed turn out it wasnt the for loop its the replacing the elements in my pandas that slow it down. 
So Im just gonna go figure how to fix that.
Thanks again for the tip on regex tho.